# How to solve $(2k+1)(2k^2+1) = y^2$ over the positive integers

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves

How could I find a solution to $(2k+1)(2k^2+1) = y^2$ over positive integers?

WolframAlpha returns some solutions, but I was wondering if there was a way to find all of them, or prove that there are infinitely many. Here is the link to the Wolfram Alpha answer:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+%282k%2B1%29%282k%5E2%2B1%29+%3D+y%5E2+over+the+integers

This is a personal question inspired by the equation $(k+2)(4k+1) = y^2$ which is doable using elementary methods.

Comment: Hint: What's $\gcd(2k+1, 2k^2+1)$?

Comment: I found that it can be 1 or 3

Comment: Extension of the hint is that if the product of two comprime integers is a square then they’re both squares.

Comment: Please insert "content" for the question, best showing which is the source (or the inspiration for the question, if this is a personal question), giving motivation, when "W$\alpha$ returns some solutions" be kind and insert them here, why not with the code as link that computes this solutions, why do we "want them all" (especially for this equation)? Note that somebody added the [elliptic-curves] tag, suggesting that a glance at the Nagell-Lutz theorem  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagell%E2%80%93Lutz_theorem) ...

Comment: Wait I added all that, how do I get the question re opened?

Comment: Four members (including me) have voted to re-open it. I don't know how many are needed but I think it will happen soon.

Comment: @NeatMath. The Q is now open.

Comment: @dan_fulea Nagell–Lutz theorem can only provide the location of the integer solutions with finite order. It fails to find the solution $(768:21760:1)$ since it is not in the possible positions for the finite order points and it has no finite order, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another computer solution by using SAGEMATH (though we need to put it in standard form). We are indeed looking for integral points on an elliptic curve. First we transform our Diophantine equation $E_1:(2k+1)(2k^2+1) = y^2$ into the form $Y^2 = X^3 +a X^2 + b X +c$, where $a,b,c$ are integers (which SAGEMATH will compute integral points for us, assuming its algorithm is correct).

With the substitutions $k=X/64$ and $y=Y/256$, we obtain an elliptic curve in standard form with integral coefficients $E_2:Y^2 = X^3 + 32X^2+2048X+65536$. Note any integral solutions to our original problem $E_1$ will be an integral solution to this new equation $E_2$.

Using the following in SAGEMATH (which you can execute it here https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)

```
x,y = polygens(QQ,'x,y'); 
E = EllipticCurve(-y^2+x^3+32*x^2+2048*x+65536); 
E.integral_points(both_signs=True)
```

(One can also check this curve has rank 1 by using the command E.rank())

It shows the only integral solutions to $E_2$ are (in homogeneous coordinates $(X:Y:1)$)

```
[(-32 : 0 : 1),
 (-16 : -192 : 1),
 (-16 : 192 : 1),
 (0 : -256 : 1),
 (0 : 256 : 1),
 (64 : -768 : 1),
 (64 : 768 : 1),
 (160 : -2304 : 1),
 (160 : 2304 : 1),
 (768 : -21760 : 1),
 (768 : 21760 : 1)]
```

Note, by Siegel's Theorem, there can only be finitely many integral solutions (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SiegelsTheorem.html).

Here we see there are only six solutions such that $X$ is a multiple of 64 and $Y$ is a multiple of 256, namely

```
 (0 : -256 : 1),
 (0 : 256 : 1),
 (64 : -768 : 1),
 (64 : 768 : 1),
 (768 : -21760 : 1),
 (768 : 21760 : 1)
```

Recovering for $k$ and $y$ we have the only six integral solutions offered in Wolfram Alpha: $(k,y) = (0,\pm 1), (1,\pm 3),(12,\pm 85)$.

I only have a superficial understanding of this, but I will direct you here for more information:

1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve
2. Rational Points on Elliptic Curves, by Silverman.

Comment: Do you know if the algorithm used by sage math is proven to compute every integer point?

Comment: @Jyyonjj That I am not sure. Here is the documentation of the sage code function integral_points() : https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/arithmetic_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_rational_field.html#sage.schemes.elliptic_curves.ell_rational_field.EllipticCurve_rational_field.integral_points

Comment: @Jyyonjj It cites the algorithm described in "Number Theory, Volume 1: Tools and Diophantine Equations" (Section 8.7) by Cohen. Also more discussions/ref on finding integral points here: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6676/integer-points-of-an-elliptic-curve

Comment: Alright, after skimming through the section it seems that they have an algorithm that(with proof) finds all integral points, thanks for all your help.